# Delphi TComboBox Dropdown fields filtering

Tags: delphi, tcombobox

I'm using a TComboBox at Delphi. How can I filter the dropdown fields displayed when I write some text (AutoDropDown set to True), to show me just the matching fields?

Comment: are you talking about auto complete?

Comment: Maybe better fitting could be [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9466547/960757).