# TEdit with autocomplete / suggestion list

Tags: delphi, autocomplete

I've been wondering if there is a TEdit component with autocomplete function similar to jQuery autocomplete: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

I would like to attach to it a function which will seek through database by many fields with LIKE command. Then I would return a list of matching records. Maybe some DevExpress component? I am thinking of creating my own component (borderless form below the TEdit for example)

Comment: Something like this, [Google like edit/combo control for Delphi?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2012208/576719)

Comment: A lot of components exist for this purpose so adding your own seems a bit too complicated. (Also: If my memory does not fail me the early D7 times when there was no specific component for that purpose we used a combo box with csSimple sytle or something like that.)

Comment: Or this,[Auto append/complete from text file to an edit box delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465590/auto-append-complete-from-text-file-to-an-edit-box-delphi)

Comment: I would expect a combo box for this (from a UX point of view). A combo box with items filtered by what is written in its edit. From time to time it happens to me that I just forget what I wanted to search and I would stay lost with that jQuery autocomplete edit.

Answer (score 2):

The underlying edit control has support for this, as described in the documentation: [Using Autocomplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb776884.aspx) and [How to Enable Autocomplete Manually](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/hh127437.aspx).

It's going to be a little tricky for you since you need to write your own autocomplete source. That's going to involve a fair amount of COM programming. I'm not aware of any well known VCL wrapper that will simplify this for you. I'd suggest that you start with the C++ code in the MSDN links and get that to work. You are much more likely to find ready made examples based on C++ code. Once you can do this with C++, it should be relatively straightforward to translate to Delphi.

Comment: You won't be able to implement *fulltext* search (what that jQuery component does) with `IAutoComplete`. It matches the text just from the beginning; that's why I wrote [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9472014/960757) ugly bunch of code (as an example).

Answer (score 0):

use "mru edit" or "lookup combobox"