# TComboBox - how to adjust drop down list height while it is dropped down?

Tags: delphi, combobox, delphi-7

I was inspired by this question: [How to make a combo box with full-text search autocomplete support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466547/how-to-make-a-combo-box-with-fulltext-search-autocomplete-support)?

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9466547/937125) works just fine but I want to adjust the suggestion list Height/`DropDownCount` when the user types the text ***while*** the list is already dropped down.

Here is an MCVE with minor modifications - When the user starts typing, the drop down list will drop-down, and I also fixed the mouse cursor effect not being set to arrow when the list dropped down:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, StrUtils, ExtCtrls;

type
  TComboBox = class(StdCtrls.TComboBox)
  private
    FStoredItems: TStringList;
    FOldCursor: TCursor; // NEW !!!
    procedure FilterItems;
    procedure StoredItemsChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SetStoredItems(const Value: TStringList);
    procedure CNCommand(var AMessage: TWMCommand); message CN_COMMAND; 
    procedure AdjustDropDownHeight; // NEW !!!
  protected
    // NEW !!!
    procedure KeyPress(var Key: Char); override;
    procedure DropDown; override;
    procedure CloseUp; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property StoredItems: TStringList read FStoredItems write SetStoredItems;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TComboBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  AutoComplete := False;
  FStoredItems := TStringList.Create;
  FStoredItems.OnChange := StoredItemsChange;
end;

destructor TComboBox.Destroy;
begin
  FStoredItems.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TComboBox.CNCommand(var AMessage: TWMCommand);
begin
  // we have to process everything from our ancestor
  inherited;
  // if we received the CBN_EDITUPDATE notification
  if AMessage.NotifyCode = CBN_EDITUPDATE then
    // fill the items with the matches
    FilterItems;
end;

procedure TComboBox.FilterItems;
var
  I: Integer;
  Selection: TSelection;
begin
  // store the current combo edit selection
  SendMessage(Handle, CB_GETEDITSEL, WPARAM(@Selection.StartPos),
    LPARAM(@Selection.EndPos));
  // begin with the items update
  Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    // if the combo edit is not empty, then clear the items
    // and search through the FStoredItems
    if Text <> '' then
    begin
      // clear all items
      Items.Clear;
      // iterate through all of them
      for I := 0 to FStoredItems.Count - 1 do
        // check if the current one contains the text in edit
        if ContainsText(FStoredItems[I], Text) then
          // and if so, then add it to the items
          Items.Add(FStoredItems[I]);
    end
    // else the combo edit is empty
    else
      // so then we'll use all what we have in the FStoredItems
      Items.Assign(FStoredItems)
  finally
    // finish the items update
    Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
  // and restore the last combo edit selection
  SendMessage(Handle, CB_SETEDITSEL, 0, MakeLParam(Selection.StartPos,
    Selection.EndPos));

  // NEW !!! - if the list is dropped down adjust the list height
  if DroppedDown then
    AdjustDropDownHeight;
end;

procedure TComboBox.StoredItemsChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(FStoredItems) then
    FilterItems;
end;

procedure TComboBox.SetStoredItems(const Value: TStringList);
begin
  if Assigned(FStoredItems) then
    FStoredItems.Assign(Value)
  else
    FStoredItems := Value;
end;

//  NEW !!!
procedure TComboBox.KeyPress(var Key: Char);
begin
  inherited;
  if not (Ord(Key) in [VK_RETURN, VK_ESCAPE]) then
  begin
    if (Items.Count <> 0) and not DroppedDown then
      // SendMessage(Handle, CB_SHOWDROPDOWN, 1, 0); 
      DroppedDown := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TComboBox.DropDown;
begin
  FOldCursor := Screen.Cursor;
  Screen.Cursor := crArrow;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TComboBox.CloseUp;
begin
  Screen.Cursor := FOldCursor;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TComboBox.AdjustDropDownHeight;
var
  Count: Integer;
begin
  Count := Items.Count;
  SetWindowPos(FDropHandle, 0, 0, 0, Width, ItemHeight * Count +
    Height + 2, SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOZORDER or SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_NOREDRAW or
    SWP_HIDEWINDOW);
  SetWindowPos(FDropHandle, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE or
    SWP_NOZORDER or SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_NOREDRAW or SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  ComboBox: TComboBox;
begin
  // here's one combo created dynamically
  ComboBox := TComboBox.Create(Self);
  ComboBox.Parent := Self;
  ComboBox.Left := 10;
  ComboBox.Top := 10;

  // here's how to fill the StoredItems
  ComboBox.StoredItems.BeginUpdate;
  try
    ComboBox.StoredItems.Add('Mr John Brown');
    ComboBox.StoredItems.Add('Mrs Amanda Brown');
    ComboBox.StoredItems.Add('Mr Brian Jones');
    ComboBox.StoredItems.Add('Mrs Samantha Smith');
  finally
    ComboBox.StoredItems.EndUpdate;
  end;      
end;    

end.
```

I have added the `AdjustDropDownHeight` (inspired by `TCustomCombo.AdjustDropDown`) in the `FilterItems` method, but it not seems to work as expected. The window hides and it's height is not adjusted according to the actual items in the `TComboBox` while it is dropped down.

Seems like the `FDropHandle` is not responding (or handeling) the `SetWindowPos(FDropHandle, ...` in the `AdjustDropDownHeight` method.

Can this be fixed? how to adjust the height of the drop down while it is dropped down according to the actual items?

---

**EDIT:** Setting `DropDownCount := Items.Count` (as suggested in the answer) was the first thing I have tried (it sets the *max* number of items). However the drop down Window does not change its height while typing the text (while it is already dropped down). `SetDropDownCount` setter simply sets `FDropDownCount := Value`. this will set the drop down count/height the *next time* the drop down list is dropped. and I need it to change *while* it is dropped down. Hope its more clear now.

(Maybe newer Delphi versions have a different `SetDropDownCount` setter?)

---

To show better what I want:

User types `Mr`

[image]

Then `Mrs` (the height of the list is adjusted)

[image]

Then user press backspace to `Mr` (list height adjusted again):

[image]

---

**EDIT 2:**
@Dsm was correct, and gave me the right direction. newer Delphi version `SetDropDownCount` setter sends extra `CB_SETMINVISIBLE` message, and this works as expected:

```
procedure TCustomCombo.SetDropDownCount(const Value: Integer);
begin
  if Value <> FDropDownCount then
  begin
    FDropDownCount := Value;
    if HandleAllocated and CheckWin32Version(5, 1) and ThemeServices.ThemesEnabled then
      SendMessage(Handle, CB_SETMINVISIBLE, WPARAM(FDropDownCount), 0);
  end;
end;
```

For older version define:

```
const
  CBM_FIRST               = $1700;
  CB_SETMINVISIBLE        = CBM_FIRST + 1;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is actually as simple as this

```
procedure TComboBox.AdjustDropDownHeight;
begin
  DropDownCount := Items.Count;
end;
```

I tested using your MCVE and it works well.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. Do you actually see the drop down windows change its height when you type text *while* it is already dropped down? `SetDropDownCount` does actually nothing but set `FDropDownCount := Value`. and it will affect the height/count the *next time* it is dropped down.

Comment: for me it changed the height instantly, i.e *not* the next time it drops down. Maybe it is the version of Delphi. I am on Berlin. I'll have a look at the setter tomorrow and see if it gives a clue.